# what's the meaning of 'commit one's country'

Tags: meaning, phrases

> Since he was not given plenipotentiary poweres by his government, he
> could not **commit his country** without consulting his superiors.

According to the dictionary,

a word 'commit' has many meanings like the below.

> 1.to give in trust or charge; consign.
>
> 2.to consign for preservation:
>
> 3.to pledge (oneself) to a position on an issue or question
>
> 4.to bind or obligate, as by pledge or assurance; pledge:
>
> 5.to entrust, especially for safekeeping; commend:
>
> 6.to do; perform; perpetrate:
>
> 7.to consign to custody

I'm not sure which one suits in the sentence I quoted.

I guess 6 is correct.

Does 'commit one's country' mean 'manage one's country'?

Comment: No, it means *commit*. and I would suggest the meaning closest to your example is number 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Commit](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commit) in the sentence means:

> obligate, bind: *a contract committing the company to complete the
>   project on time*

Usage of [commit one's country](http://www.heritage.org/research/reports/2013/11/the-eurasian-union-undermining-economic-freedom-and-prosperity-in-the-south-caucasus) is well explained in the link. It means *to bind his country to do something with the presidential or its equivalent authority or power*.

While Azerbaijan has in the past rejected EAU membership, Armenia—already heavily dependent on aid from Russia—is in a weaker position and has Russian troops stationed on its soil. Its President, Serge Sargsyan, has **committed his country** *to join the Customs Union*, the precursor to the Eurasian Union, while suspending the Associate Membership agreement with the EU that Armenia negotiated for three years.

Answer (score 1):

It’s *4) bind or obligate.*

It's saying he wasn’t allowed to promise his country would do something without making sure his superiors were okay with it.